How to not download the binary when we reach an URL that finish by .exe
I want to be able to check the content of binary file before downloading it on a browser when I reach a .exe file with a URL (something like www.example.com/test.exe)
I did not find anything to do it, i f i can do it with a web extension it would be great also ! But when I tried just to reach the binary files, I have seen that I can not execute any script in my extension before begin the downloading. So I am a little bit lost ahah
Thank you for your time !!

You shall create a page like download.html which receives the file link using get method, then do anything you want and then use this js to download.
window.open(/*url of file caught from GET*/)

Having question how to find GET values? look here!
Good luck!
